If I wanted to include a picture and have it be visible when in China, what are my options?
SE is accessible from inside China; imgur, the host for images on SE is (currently) not. Suppose I wanted to include a picture in my question or answer, and have it be visible to someone in China; what are my (100% legal) options?

Ideally it would be a website that seems reliable from both outside and inside China...
Uploading to imgur via SE's interface seems to be possible for some reason, so point 1 is not strictly required
is this even allowed? I'd guess that only imgur posts are technologically allowed to be made 'inline'.

I'll tag feature-request but obviously I'm not asking for or expecting SE-wide change to benefit users in China, better tag suggestions welcome :)

I feel like this is impossible unless you use a VPN. I doubt that a request for StackExchange to change its image hosting methods is going to work. This is really an issue of the Chinese government, rather than StackExchange.

Yes, @droooze I do not want SE to change anything, hence the hesitation to tag feature-request...but I would like to know if there is anything I can do. An example for what I'm hoping for; perhaps direct-linking images is allowed? And causes no security risk? I don't know. If yes, is it feasible? Do such image hosts exist? Yes to all the above should be an answer to this. Maybe I should change the tag (discussion perhaps?) so people don't think I'm hoping for change from higher up in SE.inc?

For users wanting to view images, there's a workaround involving copy/pasting the Imgur URL into an alternate image hosting site and viewing it there.  It's legally problematic, so I asked about a workaround on meta.SE: As a workaround to Imgur being blocked, is there a image hosting site which allows URL uploads and does not violate CC BY-SA 4.0 copyright?

You can use the <img src="[image URL]"> html markup.
For example, <img src="https://i146.photobucket.com/albums/r277/CabanaJul/balance.gif"> gives some random PhotoBucket image:

This works fine here in China.  You just need the image file hosted at a site that's not blocked.

I also note that several people on meta.SE complain about Imgur being blocked at their workplace.  I think it's because Imgur also hosts a lot of porn.

Well I suppose that solves that then, I didn't think I'd ever write another line of html :) thanks
